# Mock DB connection in jTDS?

Tags: jtds

Is it possible to mock Sybase DB connection in jTDS?

I'd like to do some development on my laptop but don't want to install the whole Sybase ASE.

Thank you,
Arkadiy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need full support for TransactSQL then I think its probably best to run a free Sybase or SQL server on your laptop, for example the [Anywhere developer edition](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1016644).

However, if your application can work within a subset of SQL functionality and you are not specifically testing jTDS you can try using an in memory database like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html).